# Problema com subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Boa noite,

Preciso trazer o resultado completo da subquery:

```
(select (valor * 0.05) from tbl_exames) as 'Valor dos Exames',
```

Em uma delimiter:

```
delimiter //
create procedure comissao(idmedico int)
begin
    select nome_medico as 'Médico',
    (select (valor * 0.05) from tbl_exames) as 'Valor dos Exames',
    (select sum(valor * 0.05) from tbl_exames) as 'Valor Total das Comissões'
    from tbl_medico where id_medico = idmedico;
end //
delimiter ;
```

Onde dá o erro: Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Ele vai listar todos os valores dos exames sendo 5% dela.

Edit:

Eu gostaria que ele aparecesse da seguinte forma:

---

Médico - nome

---

Valor dos Exames - valor1, valor2, valor3, etc..

---

Valor Total das Comissões - Soma dos valores acima

---

Edit2:

Seria assim, mas próximo do que eu esperava:

```
delimiter //
create procedure comissao(idmedico int)
begin
    select nome_medico as 'Médico',
    (select sum(valor * 0.05) from tbl_exames) as 'Valor Total das Comissões'
    from tbl_medico where id_medico = idmedico union
    select tipo as 'Exame', (valor * 0.05) as 'Valor da Comissão' from 
tbl_exames;
end //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Fiz uma alteração na resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ele esta falando que a subquery esta retornando mais de 1 valor, veja a sua primeira subquery, não tem o "sum" então ela vai retornar varios valores

```
select (valor * 0.05) from tbl_exames
```

Ou você adiciona o sum nela, ou repense sua query.

Desta forma deve resolver o seu problema:

```
delimiter //
create procedure comissao(idmedico int)
begin
    select nome_medico as 'Médico',
    (select sum(valor) from tbl_exames) as 'Valor dos Exames',
    (select sum(valor * 0.05) from tbl_exames) as 'Valor Total das Comissões'
    from tbl_medico where id_medico = idmedico;
end //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Resolvi mudando na Edit2, mas vou aceitar a sua resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNicaretta quando você mesmo encontra a solução para seu problema, você pode e deve responder. Neste caso em específico, eu creio que a solução do WictorChaves seja equivalente à sua da edição da questão, portanto no cenário atual não vejo necessidade de fazer uma auto-resposta